# What do these two sentences mean: "The girl's eyes were wild with fear."

Tags: sentence-meaning

**The girl's eyes were wild with fear.** They shone out of her dirty face. Her knees were covered in blood from the fall. She had a sharp pain in her side from running. But she ran.
**There was a high lovers' moon** and the night was full of dark shadows. The shadows followed her. The shadows could kill her.

I don't understand the two sentences in bold above paragraph. At least I have an idea about the first sentence that what it means. But I have no idea about second sentence. It comes nonsense to me.

Answer (score 1):

> The girl's eyes were wild with fear.

The girl is experiencing fear, and this has altered the appearance/movements of her eyes.

We may surmise that the word "wild" means she appears less civilised and more primitive or animal-like - she is focused purely on survival, and is more in touch with or inclined to follow basic instincts than higher cognition. When I hear this phrasing, I picture her eyes being very wide, perceiving a lot of information, and perhaps darting around a bit. She anticipates an attack, and is ready to fight back.

> There was a high lovers' moon

This is a common symbolism, where we often see the idea of lovers partaking of some activity (eating, walking, etc.) by the light of the moon. Typically, the moon will be full, large in its appearance, and beautiful; and this would be commonly understood as the meaning of the term "lovers' moon". The "high" just means high in the sky.